# Embedded binary's bundle identifier is not prefixed with the parent app's bundle identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I trying to compile the [Lister example code from app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014701) and I keep getting the error below:

```
error: Embedded binary's bundle identifier is not prefixed with the parent app's bundle identifier.
Embedded Binary Bundle Identifier:  com.example.apple-samplecode.Lister.watchkitextension
Parent App Bundle Identifier:       nz.co.icaro.listner.Lister
```

I already change the bundle name, the name of each separate project, I also change the developer account for each relevant part, try to clean, build, restart xcode but it seems that the Embedded binary's bundle identifier does not change.
I follow the pdf instructions step by step but still, no luck!

Can anyone see what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to build this project by deleting all the existent binary and temporary files from XCode and rebuilding each project individually.